# How to iterate over items from a Flux?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I need to iterate over a Flux and get object from the previous and the posterior position of a certain index. Is this possible? How can I implement this?

Comment: I dunno why you would do that, but Flux has the collectList method you can then block and get the list. I cant post this as an answer because I think you are not working in the reactive way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like:

```
yourFlux.collectList().flatMap(x -> {    //here you can, for example, x.get(0); });
```